# Can we view the source for say signal.h file in Linux

Tags: c, manpage

Do man pages provide the source code for a particular file like
for example signal.h or is there any way to view it out of the box? 
I am using ubuntu from WSL (although that shouldn't make any difference)

Comment: It's a header file, like any other file. Simply display it with `cat` or `less` or whatever else you choose.

Comment: Headers file are usually installed in `/usr/include`, you may need to install the package `libc6-dev`. use `dpkg -S signal.h` to see what installed package contain it, or install `apt-file` to search in non-installed packages.

Comment: You are not confusing libraries with the headers which declare their API and actually asking about seeing the source files which went into building the libs, are you?

Comment: I did cat /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/signal.h... It showed #include <signal.h> Thats weird. I wanted to see the code or whatever text is there inside the signal.h file.

Comment: Can we also see the code for kill function how it is implemented internally?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically, header files are contained at `/usr/include/` directory. So if you open `/usr/include/signal.h`, you will see full header file. Never tried it on WSL, but it should be fine.

Comment: Yes Thanks I got it there

Comment: @pensee glad you understood! It would be nice if you will press checkmark button near answer that helped you :)

Comment: This doesnt seem to apply for the case where file is **#include <sys/types.h>** I coudnt find this types.h under /usr/include

Comment: @pensee it should be located at `/usr/include/sys/types.h`

Comment: @pensee that's strange. On Linux it is located there. Seems like WSL really makes difference

Comment: Looks like for 64 bit its in the location - cat /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/types.h

Answer (score 1):

You can search for `signal.h` on your computer; it'll be there plain to read.

It likely doesn't contain all the source code for your OS's signal support, though. For that you can go to [the Ubuntu source code, which is available online](https://askubuntu.com/a/167474/1113146).

man pages are text documentation for humans, not source code.

Comment: There is no need to download full source code for header files, it should be already downloaded

Comment: @Vlad Yes, I said that.

Comment: Note: The version you find online might not be the exact version that's installed on your computer, but it should be close enough.

Comment: @user253751 Why would it be different? Assuming you lookup the correct tagged source...

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings That's a big assumption given how many versions of how many Linux distributions there are.

Comment: @user253751 The OP's only running _one_, so that's all they need to look up. The source is available for every version of an open source Linux distribution. That's literally what open source means.